# How to handle different codes in response Model in Clean Architecture Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, uikit, clean-architecture

I am trying to re-write my app by adding Clean Architecture, and I have a problem. I get codes from my server in my every response. Codes can be `1,-1,32`, etc. Some codes are good to go, like they are success codes, and all negative codes are errors, and some codes like `32` indicate session has expired and I need to logout, while some codes indicate I need to navigate to specific screen.
I am not sure in which layer I should handle these codes.
I have following layers in my app.

> ViewController -> ViewModel -> UseCase -> Repo -> NetworkManager

From NetworkManager, I get the decoded response model, that model contains code.
Should I handle it in Usecase or Repo? And how should I handle it?
I want to have a generic solution.
This is what I have tried so far.

```
class LoginUCImpl: LoginUC {

@Injected(\AppDIContainer.loginRepository) var loginRepo
@Injected(\AppDIContainer.responseCodeHandler) var responseCodeHandler

func getUser(username: String, password: String) async -> Result<Bool, Error> {
    let res = await loginRepo.getUser(username: username, password: password)
    switch res {
    case .success(let data):
         ************** Should I handle it here??? **************
        return .success(true)
    case .failure(let error):
        return .failure(error)
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
class LoginRepositoryImpl: LoginRepository {

@Injected(\AppDIContainer.requestManager) var requestManager

func getUser(username: String, password: String) async -> Result<GetUser, Error> {
    let request = LoginRequest.getUser(userName: username, password: password)
    do {
        let res: Result<GetUserDTO, Error> = try await requestManager.makeRequest(with: request)
        switch res {
        case .success(let data):
         ************** Should I handle it here??? **************
            return .success(data.toDomain())
        case .failure(let failure):
            return .failure(failure)
        }
    } catch let error {
        return .failure(error)
    }
  }
}
```

I have made a class that handles different response codes.

```
protocol ResponseCodeHandler {
  func handle(responseCode: String)
}

class ResponseCodeHandlerImpl: ResponseCodeHandler {
func handle(responseCode: String) {
    switch responseCode {
    case "0", "1":
        print("Normal Response")
    case "32":
        print("Session Expire")
    case "112":
        print("Forgot password")
    default:
        print("invalid response code")
     }
   }
 }
```

But I don't know how to implement it here in. I am also confused about how will I handle navigation here.
Any help or guidance is much appreciated. Thanks